# Add missing values in the list by comparing the other list and vice versa

Tags: python, list

I am trying to add the missing values to the list by comparing the other list. If the data is not present in list_1 which is there in list_2, in same index of list_2 we have to add "Missing" in list_1

```
list_1 = [('state', 'YES', 'varchar'), ('quantity', 'YES', 'int')]

list_2 = [('name', 'NO', 'varchar'), ('marks', 'YES', 'varchar'), ('state', 'YES', 'int')]
```

expected output of the lists is

```
list_1 = [("missing",),("missing",),('state', 'YES', 'varchar'), ('quantity', 'YES', 'int'))]

list_2 = [('name', 'NO', 'varchar'), ('marks', 'YES', 'varchar'), ('state', 'YES', 'int'),("missing",)]
```

I have tried the below, but its not working.

```
new_list1 = set(list1).difference(list2)
new_list2 = set(list2.difference(list1)

 for i in new_list1:
     for x in range(len(list_2)):
         if list_2[x][0] == i:
             list_1.insert(x, ("missing",))

 for i in new_list2:
          for x in range(len(list_1)):
         if list_1[x][0] == i:
             list_2.insert(x, ("missing",))
```

Some one help to resolve this

Comment: this structure for information representation is frankly very ill suited for this task. You should really consider a dict instead.

Comment: are you considering this : ('state', 'YES', 'varchar') and this : ('state', 'YES', 'int') the same ?

Comment: yes, I am considering only the first element of the tuple

Comment: I don't think this is really possible. E.g. if you have two lists `[a, b]` and `[a, c]` (`a,b,c` being short for tuples in your lists), should the resulting lists be `[a, b, missing]` and `[a, missing, c]` or `[a, missing, b]` and `[a, c, missing]`? In other words, you can't always unambiguously infer the order of all elements from your two lists. And if order does not matter, you should indeed use dictionaries.

Comment: Any one of the result is fine either [a, b, missing] and [a, missing, c] or [a, missing, b] and [a, c, missing]

Comment: Please describe in more detail what "its not working" means. Are you getting an error? Incorrect results? Please include them in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really possible to infer the total ordering of all the keys from your two lists, and from your comments, order is not really important anyway. Thus, it would be much easier to use dictionaries instead, mapping the key (the first element of the tuples that you use for deciding equality) to the actual tuples.

```
>>> d1 = {a: (a,b,c) for a,b,c in list_1}                                   
>>> d2 = {a: (a,b,c) for a,b,c in list_2}
```

You can then easily get all the keys from both (or any number of) dictianaries and use a dictionary comprehension to get the final dict with "missing" values.

```
>>> all_keys = set(d1) | set(d2)                                            
>>> {k: d1.get(k, "missing") for k in all_keys}                             
{'quantity': ('quantity', 'YES', 'int'),
 'marks': 'missing',
 'name': 'missing',
 'state': ('state', 'YES', 'varchar')}
```

And analogeously for `list_2`. Of course, you can also use a list comprehension. It will be more difficult to know which items are missing, but corresponding items will be in the same position, although not necessarily the same (relative) positions as in the original lists.

```
>>> [d1.get(k, "missing") for k in all_keys]                               
[('quantity', 'YES', 'int'), 'missing', 'missing', ('state', 'YES', 'varchar')]
>>> [d2.get(k, "missing") for k in all_keys]                               
['missing', ('marks', 'YES', 'varchar'), ('name', 'NO', 'varchar'), ('state', 'YES', 'int')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't complete this using your tuple structure, but the general idea should be the same.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [0,1,7, 2,3]
new = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
    new += ["missing"]
    if list2[i] in list1:
        new[i] = list2[i]

list1 = new
print(list1)
```